# How to create one-to-one relationship?(SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Goods
(
    GoodsCode           INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE Complaint
(
    Num          INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
);
```

How do one-to-one relationship between them?

Comment: Probably this is only the example that is ... well ... not that good. But in a one-to-one relationship, you could only have *one complaint per good*.

Answer (score 4):

Since both of these columns are primary key columns so you cannot have duplicates in either of the columns, but Column `Num` in table `Complaint` references to column `GoodsCode` in table `Goods` hence it is a One-to-One Relation.

```
CREATE TABLE Goods
(
    GoodsCode           INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
);


CREATE TABLE Complaint
(
    Num          INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
      FOREIGN KEY (Num) REFERENCES Goods(GoodsCode)
);
```

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning that with this solution, you enforce both parts of the one-to-one relationship to have the _same primary key_. Which is efficient, but not mandatory nor even necessary desirable in a 1-to-1 relationship.